# How to generate ObjectIds for embedded documents from ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I see here:
[[How can I create unique IDs for embedded documents in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144852/how-can-i-create-unique-ids-for-embedded-documents-in-mongodb][1])

that in Ruby I can do something like this:

```
oid = BSON::ObjectId.new
```

I wonder, what would be the equivalent in ReactiveMongo.

Thank you.

Comment: You can have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/#reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID$)

Comment: Found it in the meantime, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it... we can use reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID.generate()